# Performing math function in array for Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, math

I'm new to programming, and having a difficult time taking the array below and performing a mathematical expression on each index then printing the result.

```
var projectOne = [ 1, 3, 5, 0, 6]
for addition in projectOne {
    print( projectOne "plus 4 is" \projectOne = projectOne + 4)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to transform the array by adding 4 to the value at each index and then print the transformed value?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the addition (array element) inside your loop. You should also take a look at Apple docs [String interpolation](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjNqK3t55HLAhWJEZAKHVUIDJAQygQIIzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fprerelease%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FSwift%2FConceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FStringsAndCharacters.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014097-CH7-ID292&usg=AFQjCNFmLWlPFCoYaNTXGpExz_5R8MPkpg&sig2=HUQUcJDjiMGWaQKaM4mK8Q).

```
print("\(addition) plus 4 is \(addition + 4)")
```

If you would like to increment all elements in your array you can enumerate it and add 4 to each element as follow:

```
for (index,element) in projectOne.enumerate() {
    projectOne[index] += 4

    print("\(element) plus 4 is \(element + 4)")
}

print(projectOne)  // "[5, 7, 9, 4, 10]\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `map` and a `closure` to transform the array:

```
var projectOne = [ 1, 3, 5, 0, 6]
projectOne = projectOne.map() {
  let newValue = $0 + 4
  print("\($0) plus 4 is \(newValue)")
  return newValue
}
```

You can also use a `for..in` loop like this:

```
var projectOne = [ 1, 3, 5, 0, 6]

for (index, value) in projectOne.enumerate() {
  projectOne[index] += 4
  print("\(value) plus 4 is \(projectOne[index])")
}
```

Comment: your second loop is exactly the same as what I already suggested

Comment: Yes, they are similar. It's one of the two main ways to approach the problem.

Comment: you can simplify the map `projectOne = projectOne.map {$0 + 4}`

Comment: True, but the question wanted to transform and print. That simplification doesn't do both.